# Opel Corsa 1.4 brakes engages on its own

Tags: brakes, car, brake-rotor, abs

My car Opel Corsa 1.4 2009 is been driven just 36k km. A strange problem started a few days back. When I drive more than 10 km in city and restart the car with a small wait(<5 mins) the car hesitates in a few km and eventually doesn’t move at all. If I wait for like 20 mins and start again the car goes on normally unless the stop/start happens after next >10 km. I thought it was the fuel pump/filter/O2 sensor but all looks good. After having the issue repeatedly, I understood its the brakes that engages on its own and I’m just pushing the gas with brakes on, making the car vibrate with a strange smell.

On opening the brakes I see the front brake pads and disc are quite damaged, no wonder I had put a lot of strain to move the car to understand the problem.
Certainly the brakes needs to be changed but I still don’t understand whats causing the brakes to engage. Even if I change the brake it might get damaged again.

Can some electrical or hydraulic be the reason? Since my car has ABS, can the ABS trigger suddenly?

The car needs to be driven for a while before the problem occurs so I guess something is happening because of the heat. Can anything in the braking system expand due to heat and get engaged if not electric?

Note: No codes from ODB2 reader.

Comment: "*I still don’t understand whats causing the brakes to engage*" Perhaps they are still engaged ( STUCK ) from when you stopped the car before you turned it off, if they are damaged they could be sticking. **DO NOT DRIVE THE CAR UNTIL YOU FIX THE BRAKES**.

Comment: With the engine off, in neutral, if you jack a front wheel up and rotate the wheel by hand, does it turn freely?  If you then start the engine in neutral can you still rotate the front wheel by hand freely?

Comment: @Alaska Man if the brakes were engaged how come there were no noise? Normally sticking brakes are detected from noise from the brakes? It it possible that I had a sticking brake for a long time and it all happened without a noise?

Comment: @dDebug it is not normal to hear it when you apply the brakes,if you can hear it something is wrong.DO NOT DRIVE THE CAR UNTIL IT IS FIXED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the break booster that was losing pressure and pulling the breaks automatically. The break booster membrane was defective. Brake booster replaced and works fine.